# How to change default postgresql schema with Heroku Connect?

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-postgres, heroku-connect

I can't see it in official documentation like:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-database-tables
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-faq

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself: you can change it only when creating connection.

That's is with demo plan.